# accepts_nested_attributes_for runs before controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I'm having a baffling problem. I have a LineItem model that accepts nested attributes for a Trackable and a Product. I am overriding the default trackable_attributes= and product_attributes= methods to allow me to find or initialize records. For example:

```
def trackable_attributes=(attributes)
  _trackable = Project.find_or_initialize_by_id(attributes.delete("id"))
  _trackable.attributes = attributes
  self.trackable = _trackable
end
```

When I post to the LineItemController#create, even when there's only a logging statement in it, it runs all of the posted parameters as if I'm trying to build/create a new line item. I don't have any before_filters that would be doing this on the #create method.

```
def create
  logger.info("LineItemsController#create")
end
```

Webserver logs:

```
Started POST "/line_items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-10 14:02:13 -0700
Processing by LineItemsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MY_SECRET_TOKEN", "line_item"=>{"trackable_type"=>"Project", "tax_rate"=>"0", "price"=>"0.00", "provided_on_formatted"=>"Apr 10", "trackable_attributes"=>{"company_attributes"=>{"id"=>"87", "name"=>"Handmade Design"}, "id"=>"45", "name"=>"MEdia Blitz"}, "product_attributes"=>{"id"=>"75"}, "name"=>"Design", "notes"=>"Yellow", "quantity"=>"0.00", "unit_price"=>"205.0"}, "commit"=>"+"}
Person Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = 73 LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.4ms)  UPDATE "people" SET "last_request_at" = '2013-04-10 21:02:13.861629', "perishable_token" = 'kzsB5dnCOHfykO1XMMi9', "updated_at" = '2013-04-10 21:02:13.863622' WHERE "people"."id" = 73
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
(1.2ms)  commit transaction
Account Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = 369 LIMIT 1
Person Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."account_id" = 369 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
{"company_attributes"=>{"id"=>"87", "name"=>"Handmade Design"}, "id"=>"45", "name"=>"MEdia Blitz"}
Project Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = 45 LIMIT 1
Company Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."id" = 87 LIMIT 1
trackable_attributes=(attributes)
trackable assigned
{"id"=>"75"}
  Product Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = 75 LIMIT 1
product_attributes=(attributes)
product assigned
LineItemsController#create
```

Notice that I have many logging statements scattered through my custom accepts_nested_attributes_for setters that are being called before the #create method even begins.

Is this normal? It seems to be causing problems with when I want to instantiate a new line_item the normal way in my LineItemsController#create method.

I'd really appreciate any help as I'm lost on where to start.

Comment: What gems are you using?

Comment: Do you have any `:before_filters` defined? What class does LineItemsController derive from - and does that class (or superclass, etc) have any `:before_filters` defined?

Comment: LineItemController derives from ApplicationController. All I do in ApplicationController is setup current_user and make sure it has a valid subscription. LineItemController doesn't have any before_filters for create.

Comment: I believe I've narrowed it down to an issue with the filter_resource_access of the DeclarativeAuthorization gem. Commenting out these lines allows the create method to run normally, without the nested attribute setters running first. I'll update this topic when I know for sure.

Comment: I narrowed down the issue. It was a problem with Declarative Authorization's filter_resource_access method. I removed this call and replaced it with filter_access_to calls for each method.